# Index not taking the right value within an $http.post query

Tags: javascript

I'm doing a loop like this :

```
for (var index in data) 
{
    console.log(index);    
    $http.post('server.php')
    .success(function(data, status) 
    { 
        console.log(index); 
    }
}
```

The first `console.log()` displays : `0,1,2,3,4,5`

The second `console.log()` displays : `5,5,5,5,5,5`

And I have really no idea why. Is it because of the fact that i'm using 2 variables named `data` ? I tried renaming one, but it didn't fixed the issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Comment: @NikhileshKV Possibly, but the question must be a question, the link you proposed assumes the user knows what to look for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use *Closures* in this aspect. The closure, *"packs"* the value of the index, while it gets executed at a callback, later.

```
for (var index in data) {
  (function(index) {
    $http.post('server.php')
    .success(function(data, status) {
      console.log(index);
    });
  })(index);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Use **`Closures`**, *The function defined in the closure 'remembers' the environment in which it was created.* [[*From docs*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures)]

```js
for (var index in data) {
  (function(index) {
    $http.post('server.php')
      .success(function(data, status) {
        console.log(index);
      });
  })(index);
}
```

Comment: This one explains why you need closures.

Answer (score 0):

Closure. If it's hard to understand it's basically doing this:

```
function doPostCall(index) {
    $http.post('server.php')
    .success(function(data, status) { 
        console.log(index); 
    }
}

for (var index in data) {
    console.log(index);    
    doPostCall(index)
}
```

See, it's just separating the post into it's own function with it's own index variable that is guaranteed to not change from outside/